# conflict between mathabx and other packages

Tags: incompatibility

I need to write the symbol of the earth, which is found in the package mathabx. When I compile my script I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \iint already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.505 ...d{\iint}{\DOTSI\protect\MultiIntegral{2}}.
```

It looks like a conflict between different packages.

Here is a sample of my latex script, with the packages I am using:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,psdextra]{hyperref}

\usepackage{mathabx}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    U_{\Earth}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I cannot understand what is wrong.

Comment: Can you please create a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/32374) with emphasis on the minimal? Delete all the packages except what you need to draw the `\Earth` symbol, then add the other packages back in one at a time until you get the error.

Comment: You also have a typo: `end{equation}` needs an `\\` before it.

Comment: Apart from the typo darthbith detected: Try `\earth` from the `wasysym` package

Comment: Use `amsmath` package before `mathabx`. Works fine.

Comment: @ ferahfeza: Why is it so?

Comment: See [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As egreg suggested, see [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font) for importing a single character from another font.  To get `\Earth`, I did the following.  If you unccoment these two lines in the MWE, `\usepackage{fonttable}` and `\fonttable{mathb10}`, you will get a font table printed out it from which it can be ascertained that `\Earth` is glyph `"43` (hexadecimal).  That allowed me to invoke in the preamble, `\DeclareMathSymbol{\Earth}{3}{mathb}{"43}` to import just that symbol.  One may have to do a little trial and error in the process... originally I searched the `matha` font series and did not find `\Earth`, so by trial and error, I tried the `mathb` series and found the glyph.  All the `\DeclareFontShape` stuff I just copied from Alan Munn's answer, substituting `mathb` for `matha`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,psdextra]{hyperref}

%\usepackage{mathabx}

\usepackage{amsmath}

% Setup the mathb font (from mathabx.sty)
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathb
      <10.95> mathb10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathb12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

% Define a subset character from that font (from mathabx.dcl)
% to completely replace the \subset character, you can replace
% \varsubset with \subset

\DeclareMathSymbol{\Earth}{3}{mathb}{"43}
%\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
%\fonttable{mathb10}
  \begin{equation}
    U_{\Earth}
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]