# mathabx conflicts ngerman?

Tags: mathabx

I noticed that the order of loading *mathabx* and *ngerman* is essential. In this non-working minimal example

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
$\rightarrow$
\end{document}
```

which creates the error

```
[...]\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\mathabx\mathabx.dcl
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   \protect
l.435 ...eMathSymbol{<}            {3}{matha}{"A0}
```

the problem can be avoided by reordering the includes to

```
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{ngerman}
```

which appears odd to me. Is that a bug or a feature?

If I were only using one symbol, I would follow the suggestion mentioned in [conflict between mathabx and other packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176941/conflict-between-mathabx-and-other-packages), but with more symbols, that solution is rather annoying.

Comment: The `ngerman` package is obsolete; you should do `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not at all surprising that loading `ngerman` can lead to incompatibilities: the last update to the package was in 1998.

The order

```
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{mathabx}
```

creates a number of errors. This is because the `ngerman` package immediately makes `"` into a shorthand, which conflicts with *any* package using hexadecimal notation for numbers: hexadecimal numbers in TeX are prefixed by `"`<sub>12</sub>, but after loading `ngerman` you have `"`<sub>13</sub>.

General solution: don't load `ngerman` or `german` at all costs. Instead, do

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
```