# Is there a symbol similar to $\preccurlyeq$ but with both ends aligned?

Tags: symbols

I wonder if there is a latex symbol similar to

`$\preccurlyeq$`

but aligned at both ends. Please help. Thanks.

[image: image generated by $\precurlyeq$]
[image: the version with both ends aligned]

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}  
$\preccurlyeq$
\end{document}`  Of course, I'd hate to load the whole `mathabx` package.

Comment: @Steven, Thanks!!

Comment: You can use an approach like here, to extract just that one symbol from `mathabx`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176941/conflict-between-mathabx-and-other-packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I grab just that symbol from `mathabx`, so as not to overwrite the whole symbol set.

If you uncomment the two `fonttable` references in my MWE, you will see how I determined that the desired symbol was in slot `"A4`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto,psdextra]{hyperref}

%\usepackage{mathabx}

\usepackage{amsmath}

% Setup the mathb font (from mathabx.sty)
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * mathb
      <10.95> mathb10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> mathb12
      }{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

% Define a subset character from that font (from mathabx.dcl)
% to completely replace the \subset character, you can replace
% \varsubset with \subset

\DeclareMathSymbol{\preccurlyeq}{3}{mathb}{"A4}
%\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
%\fonttable{mathb10}
  \begin{equation}
    A \preccurlyeq B
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another alternative is the `stix` fonts

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stix}
\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    A \preccurlyeq B
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]